# FTP client - get file in one command

Tags: ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I execute FTP commands on one line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61429/how-do-i-execute-ftp-commands-on-one-line)

I have the following FTP client conversation:

```
variscite@variscite-desktop:~$ ftp 192.168.100.10
Connected to 192.168.100.10.
220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Name (192.168.100.10:variscite): anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> get hello hello
local: hello remote: hello
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.                                                                       
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for hello (7796 bytes).                                                         
226 Transfer complete.                                                                                                  
7796 bytes received in 0.01 secs (702.8 kB/s)                                                                           
ftp> exit                                                                                                               
221 Goodbye.
```

Is it possible to do this in one command, or write a shell script which does the same? Client computer is Ubuntu 12.04, and I need to do this without installing additional packages.

Comment: I never tried this with FTP, but I think you just need to specify these commands in a bash file.

Comment: @Rinzwind - I cannot use the answer to this question, because lftp is not available.

Comment: Ok :) do you have scp? I always use scp for this.

Comment: @Rinzwind - yes, scp is available.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While I agree that `scp` is better, it's not only that your client needs the `scp` command, your server needs to support that as well ofcourse. Enough situations where you can just reach the server through FTP, isn't there?

If you want to get a file from FTP you could just use `wget` ?

```
wget ftp://username:password@SERVERNAME/directory/file
```

Comment: `wget ftp://anonymous:@192.168.100.10/hello` - got it working. Thanks.

Comment: I added also chmod +x hello since this is executable.

Comment: What if user name or password includes "@" chareacter like username "abc@ddd.com" or password like "abc@2017"

Comment: I would escape those with a "\", so "abc\@ddd.com"

Comment: Hi, how could we list directory?